# Rename a url and always show new url when old url is entered

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, redirect, nginx

I am using codeigniter framework and nginx.

I used routes of codeigniter to redirect http://sitename.com/pagename to http://sitename.com/better-new-pagename. That works fine.

But my problem is that http://sitename.com/pagename is also available so, that might be detected by google as content duplication.

How can i always show http://sitename.com/better-new-pagename whenever http://sitename.com/pagename or http://sitename.com/better-new-pagename entered?

I tried to edit nginx config like this:

```
location /pagename {
    rewrite ^/.* http://sitename.com/better-new-pagename permanent;
}
```

which end up giving too many redirects error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an nginx user, but this *should* do it for you:

```
location /pagename {
    rewrite ^/pagename$ http://$server_name/better-new-pagename permanent;
}
```

Or, you could try this:

```
location /pagename {
    return 301 http://$server_name/better-new-pagename;
}
```